# Divide an object array in separate objects

Tags: node-red

I have this object in Node-Red:

```
{
  "topic":
  [
    {
      "nodeid": "ns=1;s=sensor1"
    },
    {
      "nodeid": "ns=1;s=sensor2"
    },
  ],
  "payload": [
    {
      "value": 1234
    },
    {
      "value": 6789
    },
    .....
    .....
  
    ],
  "datatype": [    
    {
      "datatype": "Int16"
    },
    {
      "datatype": "Int16"
    },
  ]
}
```

I want  separate sequences of messages:

```
{
  "_msgid": "xxxxx1",
  "payload": 1234,
  "topic": "ns=1;s=sensor1",
  "datatype": "Int16"
}



{
  "_msgid": "xxxxx2",
   "payload": 6789,
   "topic": "ns=1;s=sensor2",
    "datatype": "Int16"
}
```

I tried with "for" loop but don't have find a solution.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72275427/edit) the question to show us the code you tried and we can help you fix it, but Stack Overflow won't just supply code based on requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried follow valid solution:

```
var msgLen = msg.topic.length;

var idNodeArray = msg.topic;
var datatypeArray = msg.datatype;
var valueArray = msg.payload;
var outMessages = [];




msg.topic = [];
msg.payload = [];
msg.datatype = [];

for (var i = 0; i < msgLen; i++)
{
     outMessages = { "topic": idNodeArray[i].nodeid, 
     "datatype":datatypeArray[i].datatype, 
     "payload":valueArray[i].value};

      node.send(outMessages);
}
```

return;